# Upgrading RAM of a MacBook

Tags: hardware, upgrade, memory

Is it possible to upgrade memory to 8 GB my model of MacBook? The manual says no, but on the web some people have made some videos about the upgrade. I don't know if any of them are fake.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site:

[Other World Computing RAM upgrade for MacBook 6,1](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_White)

http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_White

It seems it's possible to upgrade.

Comment: Other World Computing, at macsales.com (the link above), is a great place to look. They specialize in upgrading the RAM in Macs, and they have expertise in exceeding the recommended Apple specs where that's possible. Thanks to them I have a 2007 MacBook Pro with 6GB of RAM, even though Apple has always said that only 4GB is possible with my model.

Comment: Great @WheatWilliams!

Comment: My MacBook Pro officially supports 4GB, but thanks to Other World it's now running 8GB without trouble. Cheap, too!

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded. It worked!

So, different as it said in manual.. yes my Mac Version supports 8GB .

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]